# Can the new Chatter API Communities resource create a Visualforce Tabs community?

Tags: community, connect-api

In Summer '19, we got access to a [new `POST` method](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_chatter_api.htm#rn_chatter_connect) on the `connect/communities` endpoint, allowing for programmatic creation of a Community:

> Make a POST request to the existing /connect/communities resource with the new Community Input request body.

The resource is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_communities_list.htm) and takes a JSON body:

```
{
   "name":"The Capricorn Cafe",
   "urlPathPrefix":"capricorncafe",
   "templateName":"Customer Service",
   "description":"Coffee and coffee products for the most discerning tastes."
}
```

I would like to use this endpoint to create a Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce community. However, making this call with `"templateName": "Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce"` yields

> {'errorCode': 'INVALID_INPUT', 'message': 'The specified community template does not exist.'}]

If you make a request to the [Community Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_communities_templates.htm) endpoint, it does indeed include an entry called `"Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce"`. However, using a GET to `connect/communities` to obtain information on existing Communities, Visualforce communities shows

```
    "templateName" : null,
```

None of the following options work:

- Percent-encoding the name.
- Omitting the `templateName` entirely.
- Passing `null`
- Passing the literal string `"null"`
- Passing an empty string

All yield the same error.

Is this possible? What input is the endpoint looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is documented, but I figured it out by looking at the outbound requests from the Communities wizard in Chrome Inspector.

The template name that the Connect API accepts for Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce is "VF Template". The Community creation process can be invoked by doing

```
POST /services/data/v46.0/connect/communities
{
    "name": "My Community",
    "description": "",
    "templateName": "VF Template",
    "urlPathPrefix": "my_community"
}
```